# How to create a free Membership sign-up?

Tags: wordpress, civimember

Can someone tell me the correct setup for a FREE Membership?
Cannot figure out what to check to get rid of the error "One of parameters (value: ) is not of the type Integer", which occurs after the second page.

Doesn't seem to be a way to do this with the word "contribution" everywhere and trying to set a price to $0 didn't work like some other posts listed.

Just want a clean membership page where joining is free and no hint of needing to contribute.

Comment: can you confirm why you need it as a membership? are you just wanting to sign people up to a group so you can email them, or do you really want to track their membership status / cycle etc?

Comment: Please add some screen shot of the page and your priceset

Comment: We are tracking members and non members who must renew yearly.  We have events and services and track those as well, demographically, as a nonprofit housing 15 other nonprofits, all with different services for the community.  All services and membership are free.  The process is for tracking.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an Example of a clean FREE Membership page with no hint of needing to contribute! On the Contribution Page Config -> Memberships Tab -> make sure you select the Membership.

Note 1: you'll want to add some anti-spam control - like add a reCAPTCHA to a profile that you expose on your Contribution Page

Note 2: In Drupal we can sync Membership Type/Status -> to Drupal role - and can then create Member only content pages. Not sure if you can do that in Wordpress - but that's often our use case for a FREE Membership.

[image]

Comment: Thanks SO MUCH! The example helps to know it's possible. 
Thanks for the reCAPTCHA reminder
Using Wordpress :)

Answer (score 1):

You simply set the membership price to zero. On the demo go to [Membership Types](http://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2Fmember%2FmembershipType&reset=1) (un/pw is demo/demo as usual) and change the price of one of them to zero and see what happens at the [membership signup/renewal page](http://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/membership-page/).

As per Pete's comment you may not need a membership at all, but just have them sign up to a group instead.

But if membership makes sense, and you need member role sync to Wordpress, I've used Tadpole's [Wordpress CiviMember Role Sync Plugin](https://github.com/tadpolecc/civi_member_sync) but I see they are recommending a new one on the page.

Comment: Thanks. 

"Them" are the public at large and I don't see how groups will manage renewals etc.

I tried setting up Types which made me set up a contribution page and then got tangled up in Price Sets.  

I think I configured more than I needed to .  I need to trash and try again.  I doesn't seem to let you do just one thing but put in line items then the line items had a requirement then financial type had to be set...got lost, entirely - just want free events and registration and neither works.

I'll try this again = thx for the steps!

Answer (score 0):

I'm with Pete. Unless you have dues or expiration, you shouldn't use CiviMember to manage your membership.  Disable it so your colleagues don't get confused.

Then, create a group and then a profile that adds people to the group.  Link to that profile in "create" mode and make that your membership signup form.

Comment: will not work for us -We are tracking members and non members who must renew yearly.  We have events and services and track those as well, demographically, as a nonprofit housing 15 other nonprofits, all with different services for the community.  All services and membership are free.  The process is for tracking.